# Cannot view bookmarked map in android eoogle-maps-engine app

Tags: google-maps, maps

I have a bookmarked map in my Google maps engine when viewing via Chrome browser.

When I open the Google maps engine android app, I can only see maps created by me or shared with me. Not ones save as bookmark by me.

I have seen posts that one should export the map to KML and then import upon his own create map, but import returns an error: not supported file.

In addition I cannot delete old map create by me (the "delete this map" is grayed out)

Has some encountered one of this issues before?

[image]